# Formatting a date string in javascript for SQL insertion

Tags: javascript, sql, date, formatting, unix-timestamp

I am getting DATETIME strings in the following format from the facebook API:

```
2013-12-15T19:00:00-0800
```

I want to format this so I can properly insert it into an SQL date column. Below is the jist of the approach I've been taking. I am able to insert it into the database using these formatting techniques but when I try an SQL mechanism such as ORDER BY DATE it's not working.

```
var newDate = new Date('2013-12-15T19:00:00-0800').getTime() / 1000
```

Another approach:

```
var test = new Date('2013-12-15T19:00:00-0800')
//var newDate = new Date(test.getFullYear(), test.getMonth(), test.getDate());
```

Edit:

Below is a function showing some additional attempts at formatting the date as per the suggestions below. The order by hasn't worked for any of these approaches and the the returned type from the select statement is still "string".

```
function fbStampToDbDate(fbTimeOffSet){
    if(fbTimeOffSet.indexOf('T') > 0){
        var date = new Date(fbTimeOffSet.substring(0, fbTimeOffSet.indexOf('T')));
        var fbStamp = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
        var stamp = fbTimeOffSet.split("T");
    }else{
        var date = new Date(fbTimeOffSet);
        var fbStamp = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
         var stamp = fbTimeOffSet.split("T");
    }
    //return fbStamp;
    return stamp[0];
}
```

Comment: 2013-12-15T19:00:00-0800 is a datetimeoffset, sql datetime doesnt store any time zone info (not in MSSQL at least)

Comment: is it in that Form YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-ms ?

Comment: @яша nah the last component is the datetime offset ie 8hrs behind UTC not a millisecond component

Comment: You only want the date part, at the timezone the string was given in? `var date = datetime.substring(0,10);`

Comment: why don't you split your data through .split("T") method and just formulate in the way SQL Date would be able to read

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Unfortunately none of them have done the trick (see edit). If anyone has time to look over my new attempt and offer suggestions I'd appreciate it.